# Third party framework in Mac App Store

Tags: macos, frameworks, store

Does Apple allow additional frameworks? (Dynamic libraries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Those frameworks must, themselves, comply with the App Store guidelines. For example, not referencing private APIs or writing to forbidden file system locations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For instance, Twitter.app uses the Growl framework. You can confirm that by inspecting /Applications/Twitter.app/Contents/Frameworks.